# Send data from html form to Google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My website is based on wordpress and I am trying to create html form which could send user filled data to Google spreadsheet. 
Referring to the process mentioned in a medium post (https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175), I do not get any error but it does not write data in spreadsheet either. 
I researched other posts on stack overflow but could not find a solution. Please help in rectifying the code. Following is the code for reference:

HTML:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <base target="_top">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
     </head>
    <body>
    <form id="test-form">

      <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Field 1"/>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="Phone" placeholder="Field 2"/>
      </div>

      <div>
        <label>Email address</label>
        <input type="text" name="Email" placeholder="Field 3"/>
      </div>


      <div>
        <button type="submit"id="submit-form">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <script>
    var $form = $('form#test-form')
    $('#submit-form').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url: 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/Abvcasashjj90U/exec', 
// sheet link as saved during publish
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: $form.serializeObject()
      }).success(
        // do something
      );
    })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Google script editor

> ```
> function doGet(e){
>   return handleResponse(e);
> }
>
> //  Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
>         var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";
>
> var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service
>
> function handleResponse(e) {
>   // shortly after my original solution Google announced the LockService[1]
>   // this prevents concurrent access overwritting data
>   // [1] http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html
>   // we want a public lock, one that locks for all invocations
>   var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
>   lock.waitLock(30000);  // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.
>
>   try {
>     // next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
>     var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SCRIPT_PROP.getProperty("key"));
>     var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
>
>     // we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
>     var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
>     var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
>     var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
>     var row = []; 
>     // loop through the header columns
>     for (i in headers){
>       if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
>         row.push(new Date());
>       } else { // else use header name to get data
>         row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
>       }
>     }
>     // more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
>     sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
>     // return json success results
>     return ContentService
>           .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
>           .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
>   } catch(e){
>     // if error return this
>     return ContentService
>           .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
>           .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
>   } finally { //release lock
>     lock.releaseLock();
>   }
> }
>
> function setup() {
>     var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
>     SCRIPT_PROP.setProperty("key", doc.getId());
> }
> ```

Comment: Have you reviewed the Stackdriver logging for you Apps Script project?

Comment: I don't know if someone else has experienced my problems when debuggin doPost and doGet functions, but they don't log correctly. The only way I have managed to see the logs is to write in the PropertiesService and then read those properties. If you're having problems with your calls check what data is getting to your script and what data is the script processing. Other problems you might have been encountering is CORS. You might need to switch to JSONP, instead of JSON.

Comment: I've gone through your code and there are things that I don't quite understand. Why don't you use the [appendRow method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)) instead of the getRange method? It's much more efficient.

Comment: Hi @Rubén , Thanks for the inputs. Google script is running successfully and writing data to the spreadsheet when I ran on test mode. I looked into the console and found out the error in HTML code at  **line** url: 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/Abvcasashjj90U/exec'. The error is Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /. As an additional context, I am working on wordpress which is built on php.

Comment: @Hackerz Please add the additional information to the question. Regarding the error message, add it textually ( I think that the code line number is missing)

Comment: @Rubén: Thanks for the support. I added the script (mentioned in HTML code section above) to .js file and referred its source to html code. It helped in resolving the issue